# how can I implement fast barrier?

Tags: linux, pthreads

Now i implement my barrier.
but it didn't work well.

When i run barrier time calculate code
  pthread_barrier_wait consume 180000 us
  my barrier consume           390000 us

i don't know why and i want to make more fast barrier

Here is my barrier code

```
 82 pthread_mutex_t     mutexwait1;
 83 int wait_count = NUM_THREADS;
 84 int barrier1234(void) {                                                     
 85 
 86     int status, cancel, tmp;
 87     status = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexwait1);
 88     wait_count = wait_count - 1;
 89     if(wait_count == 0){ 
 90         pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond1);
 91         wait_count = NUM_THREADS ;  
 92     }   
 93     else
 94         status = pthread_cond_wait(&cond1, &mutexwait1);
 95 
 96     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexwait1);
 97     return status;
 98 
 99 }
```

I find some barrier_wait function but it didn't work. ( download from glibc)
  => error message(structure variable is not matching) is occur when compile barrier
  => I wonder this error is caused by version

I am using ubuntu 10.04
  Please teach me why my barrier is slow.
  And how can i implement default pthread_barrier_wait (in my platform)

Comment: Just quickly looking at this, it worries me because of the global wait_count. Also, how are you testing/timing it?  How can we work out why it's slow if we don't have your timing test harness?  180/390 ms?  That's forever!  It's human-perceptible!  M$ Word loads faster than that! It's 'very, very difficult' to make any synchronization mechanism that slow.

Comment: Also, when the condvar is broadcast, the waiting threads become ready all at once and have to contend for the mutex.  When they get the mutex, they release it again, (!) and run on.  The first thread that gets the mutex and releases it can loop round and reenter the barrier before all the other threads have left and so enter the list of threads trying to get the mutex.  It might then get in and dec the wait_count to -1...  IMHO, a barrier, once created/initialized by one thread, should not allow threads to enter the barrier until all waiting threads have left.

Comment: You need to exctly define what you want the barier to do, how it is created and how it is initialized, (and, maybe, how it is protected from multiple initializations).

Comment: The 390ms again - are you using spinlocks for the mutex etc?  If so, get rid of them an replace with kernel locks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glibc's barrier is implemented using lower level primitives, and not a mutex and condition.

Your mutex-based implementation has the obvious problem that it requires every thread which wakes up to re-acquire the mutex only to release it. This goes against the spirit of what a barrier is about: a first class primitive in its own right. (Of course, it's a good way to do a quick and dirty port of code that requires barriers to a platform that provides only mutexes and conditions.)

I wrote the first POSIX barrier functions that existed in glibc some twelve years ago, by the way. *Wink!*

Comment: Look at the source here: http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_barrier_wait.c

Comment: The OP barrier implementation is broken anyway - once it has decided to start releasing threads, there is nothing to prevent new threads, or released ones that have looped, from re-entering the barrier before the 'old' threads have all left.  Besides, 180/390ms?  Wots with that?  My dog can eat a banana faster than that.

Comment: 180/390ms means my all barrier latency 
for example 
  for(i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; 
     for(j = 0 ...)
          barrier();
like this. i don't mean one barrier latency